# How can I make Node script read .env variables

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I’m writing a node script to build a custom web.config file in a react app for deployment. When I run it, I want it to read in .env variables. But when I do, I get undefined for the vars. It seems to be reading in global vars fine, but not the local .env. My script is in a folder in the root project folder. How do I pull those .env variables?

Comment: If you're using bash or zsh to run the script, you can do the following : 

```
source .env && node index.js
```

Comment: I'm using Powershell

Comment: Are you using CRA?

Answer (score 1):

First, make .env file:

```
API_KEY = "5545f8g4:sa5h8f54d587eh8t545df5g"
```

then install dotenv on your project:

```
npm i dotenv
```

then require it in your code:

```js
require('dotenv').config()
```

then use it like that:

```js
console.log(process.env.API_KEY)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using bash or zsh to run the script, you can do the following :

```bash
source .env && node index.js
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like if I run my powershell command from the root folder it finds the .env file and reads it. I was running it from the folder I had the script in.